# Make macro which checks the type of math mode its in

Tags: math-mode, conditionals

I frequently find that I want to make a macro, say a derivative macro for example with the following syntax:

```
\def\dd #1;#2;{ return... }
```

However, I want it to check if it is inline math such as when math is wrapped between two dollar symbols `$ ... $`  or if it is in a block of math such as an `\[...\]` or `align` or `equation` environment. If the latter is the case then I want it to typeset

```
\frac{\mathrm{d} #1 }{\mathrm{d} #2 }
```

if it is inline math such as `$ ... $` then I want it to typeset

```
\mathrm{d} #1 / \mathrm{d} #2.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\mathchoice` primitive is designed for this test.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth4cm

\def\zz#1#2{\mathchoice
{\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d} #1 }{\mathrm{d}#2}}%
{\textstyle \mathrm{d} #1 / \mathrm{d} #2}%
{\scriptstyle \mathrm{d} #1 / \mathrm{d} #2}%
{\scriptscriptstyle \mathrm{d} #1 / \mathrm{d} #2}%
}
\begin{document}

$\zz{x}{y}$

\[\zz{x}{y}\]

\end{document}
```